# How convert text from hex to string to utf8

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I have set of content storing in database with hex encoded. Now I want to convert it back to readable message Following is my content

Hex code

> 0052004D0030002E003000300020804A592900204EE37801FF1A003100320033003400350036 30025C3D60C54EAB53D700200043006800690074006300680061007400205E26676576845FEB 4E505427FF01

After convert should be display like
example:

> RM0.00 聊天 代码：123456。尽情享受 Chitchat 带来的快乐吧！

I'm trying to use query like below convert the hex back to utf8 string

```
SELECT CONVERT(UNHEX(content) USING UTF8) FROM mymsg
```

I also try to set connection to charset utf8, but it still not work for me.

Comment: how to encode and insert string in database? also how to connect to database?

Answer (score 2):

I have used this function from http://www.mrleong.net/post/114389343529/unicode-hexadecimal-to-utf-8-string-conversion

and I have tried this also:

```
$data = '0052004D0030002E0030003000200053006E00610070006300680061007400204EE37801FF1A00360036003100330037003730025C3D60C54EAB53D700200053006E00610070006300680061007400205E26676576845FEB4E505427FF01';
echo iconv('UTF-16BE', 'UTF-8', hex2bin($data));
```

and used this

```
function hexToString($hex) {
return pack('H*', $hex);
}

echo mb_convert_encoding(hexToString($data), 'UTF-8', 'Unicode');
```

Their output is the same.

```
RM0.00 Snapchat 代码：661377。尽情享受 Snapchat 带来的快乐吧！
```

**Read this article also FROM PHP the wright way :**
http://www.phptherightway.com/#php_and_utf8

It explains how to use UTF-8 at the php, database and browser level.

Comment: I asked by colleague, is actually convert by using acs2. Thank for your answering